# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed in asyncpraw python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, praw, asyncpraw

I am trying to use the [asyncpraw](https://pypi.org/project/asyncpraw/) library, but I get `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`.

This is my code and traceback.

Code

```
import asyncio
import asyncpraw

async def main():
    reddit = asyncpraw.Reddit('praw_ini_name')
    print('User is', await reddit.user.me())
    await reddit.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Traceback

```
User is python_user
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000021D2898C1F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

This however does not happen (no exceptions) if I start the event loop like so

```
import asyncio
import asyncpraw

async def main():
    reddit = asyncpraw.Reddit('praw_ini_name')
    print('User is', await reddit.user.me())
    await reddit.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I am under the assumption that in newer python versions the preferred way to start an event loop is the way I have shown in the first snippet, so why does that not work? Even though it prints the output, why is my code throwing an exception?

I am on Python 3.9.2, with `asyncpraw` 7.2.0.

I have seen [Asyncio Event Loop is Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600579/asyncio-event-loop-is-closed), [Python3.x RuntimeError: Event loop is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271477/python3-x-runtimeerror-event-loop-is-closed) and [Aiohttp, Asyncio: RuntimeError: Event loop is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778019/aiohttp-asyncio-runtimeerror-event-loop-is-closed) and I believe they are not dupes. My question asks why it works with one but not the other.

If I do not use `reddit.close()` I get the following

```
User is python_user
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000025BAAAEF8B0>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000025BAAAF1640>, 174448.968)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x0000025BAAAEFA90>
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asyncio.run` explicity closes the loop on completion.

> #### [asyncio.run(coro, *, debug=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run)
>
> [...]
> This function always creates a new event loop and closes it at the end.

This means the event loop is *not* available for cleanup once `main` finishes. Cleanup must instead be done deterministically, via [async generators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.shutdown_asyncgens), or synchronously.

When managing the loop manually and not calling `loop.close()`, the loop remains available to schedule cleanup callbacks. Be aware that this does not necessarily mean cleanup is actually *run* unless the loop is explicitly resumed.

---

The problem in specific is a [known issue with aiohttp 3.x](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324).